# Graphics.fillRect inconsistent behavior - painting with negative height and width on some machines but not others

Tags: java, swing, intellij-idea

I teach a course in Java and am encountering the following problem. The project this issue is occurring on is a "paint" application. Relevant code at the bottom:

For most students, calling Graphics.fillRect and passing in a negative height and width will result in a rectangle NOT showing up on the screen. This is EXPECTED behavior based on java's documentation and the behavior I've seen across hundreds of students' machines for the past 4 years. In other words, without additional code, you can only draw a rectangle by clicking and dragging from top left to bottom right.

Suddenly, I'm seeing a few students who are passing in negative height and width into Graphics.fillRect and the rectangle draws on the screen correctly (as if a positive height and width were passed in). In other words, they can draw a rectangle by clicking and dragging from any direction on the screen without adding code to correctly calculate the top left-most corner and then getting the height and width based on that.

This is happening with people using different IDEs (Eclipse and IntelliJ). I've checked the following:

- Using Oracle JDK
- Using JDK 10.0.2 (also attempted to update my own JDK to 14.0.1 in case there was some compat level issue but was unable to reproduce)
- (In IntelliJ) Project structure > SDK and language level are correct (10)
- (In IntelliJ) Project structure > Platform SDK pointing to correct JDK version (10.0.2)
- (In IntelliJ) Run/Debug configuration point to the correct JRE version (10.0.2)
- Debugging to make sure the height and width were indeed being passed in as negative numbers
- One student completely uninstalled and reinstalled everything and is getting the same issue.

This is the relevant code (keep in mind this is a course for learning design patterns taught by a .NET dev, I know the code isn't perfect):

```java
public class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

    private Point startPoint;
    private PaintCanvasBase paintCanvas;

    public MyMouseListener(PaintCanvasBase paintCanvas){
        this.paintCanvas = paintCanvas;
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
        startPoint = new Point(e.getX(), e.getY());
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){

        // Filled in rectangle
        Graphics2D graphics2d = paintCanvas.getGraphics2D();
        graphics2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        int width = e.getX() - startPoint.getX();
        int height = e.getY() - startPoint.getY();

        graphics2d.fillRect(startPoint.getX(), startPoint.getY(), width, height);
    }
}

public class Point {
    private final int x;
    private final int y;

    public Point(int x, int y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public int getX(){
        return x;
    }

    public int getY(){
        return y;
    }
}

public class PaintCanvas extends PaintCanvasBase {

    public Graphics2D getGraphics2D() {
        return (Graphics2D)getGraphics();
    }
}

public abstract class PaintCanvasBase extends JComponent {
    public abstract Graphics2D getGraphics2D();
}

// Following lines in the main method:
// PaintCanvasBase paintCanvas = new PaintCanvas();
// paintCanvas.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener(paintCanvas));
```

What is the reason for this behaviour?

Comment: What you probably need to do is to find two machines (or two JREs) where the graphics rendering behaves differently. I don't know whether negative widths/heights should be rendered, but it is better to be able to prove the discrepancy rather then merely remembering it.

Comment: @halfer That's the current experience. On my machine I'm getting the old, correct experience. Others in the class are also getting the correct experience. There's at least 4 students with the "wrong" experience (and it seems per Gilbert's response he's getting the "wrong" experience as well).

Comment: Righto, I was wondering if you could get both the expected and unexpected experiences on the same machine, so they can be more accurately compared. Do they differ in operating system? What is the version of the JRE in each case?

Comment: @halfer Gotcha - They are unable to get both experiences on the same machines. They try running different JREs (not sure which versions). One student has two machines and is experiencing unique behavior on each machine, same JRE/JDK version, etc.

Comment: I would get JRE and OS information next, to help you spot a pattern.

Answer (score 1):

I created a simple, runnable example of a Java Swing application that draws a rectangle based on a start point and an end point.

I compiled this application to a Java 8 standard and ran it on a Java 13.0.2 JDK.  I'm using Windows 10.  The rectangle drew correctly no matter which direction I drew the rectangle.  I know that's not helpful to you, but I wanted to discuss some things I found in your code snippet.

All Swing painting must be done in the `paintComponent` method of a `JPanel`.  The `MouseAdapter` performs the `Rectangle` calculations.  The `paintComponent` method paints the `Rectangle`.

Here's my example code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class SimpleDrawingArea implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new SimpleDrawingArea());
    }

    private Rectangle rectangle;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Drawing Panel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new DrawingPanel());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public class DrawingPanel extends JPanel {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        public DrawingPanel() {
            this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 300));
            this.addMouseListener(new MyMouseListener(this));
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
            if (rectangle != null) {
                g2d.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                g2d.fillRect(rectangle.x, rectangle.y,
                        rectangle.width, rectangle.height);
            }
        }

    }

    public class MyMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {

        private DrawingPanel drawingPanel;

        private Point startPoint;

        public MyMouseListener(DrawingPanel drawingPanel) {
            this.drawingPanel = drawingPanel;
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e){
            startPoint = e.getPoint();
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e){
            Point endPoint = e.getPoint();
            int width = endPoint.x - startPoint.x;
            int height = endPoint.y - startPoint.y;
            rectangle = new Rectangle(startPoint.x, startPoint.y,
                    width, height);
            drawingPanel.repaint();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I copied your code into a fresh project and was unable to draw in directions other than top left to bottom right.

I'll integrate your best practice suggestion into my code moving forward, appreciate the insight.